# How do I modify a collection's .item template in Squarespace Developer mode?

Tags: collections, blogs, squarespace

I would like to modify the existing blog.item template for the Native template in Developer mode. I'm wondering if this is possible because when I modify the file and upload back to the server, no changes are recognized, as I see in Chrome Developer Tools. For instance, I added a class to a div, saved and uploaded, my FTP manager showed success, but the class is not there when I examine in developer tools. I have logged out (FTP) and back in too. I know FTP is working because the tweak.less file works fine.

Also, specifically what I am wanting to edit is the article meta. Author, date, likes that is displayed for each post. I mean that in a general way since I think that has to do with the squarespace system variables, which may be why I can't seem to edit it?

EDIT ************
here is the code that was there in the blog.item file

```
<header>
            {.if title}<h1 class="entry-title" data-content-field="title" itemprop="headline">{.passthrough?}<a href="{sourceUrl}">{title} <span>&rarr;</span></a>{.or}<a href="{fullUrl}">{title}</a>{.end}</h1>{.end}
            <div class="article-meta-top">
      {.section location}<div class="location">{.if addressTitle}<a href="//maps.google.com/maps?q={mapLat},{mapLng}" target="_blank" title="View map in new window"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i>{addressTitle}</a>{.end}</div>{.end}
      <span class="date"><a href="{fullUrl}"><time class="published" datetime="{addedOn|date %F}" itemprop="datePublished">{addedOn|date %B %d, %Y}</time></a></span>
       {.section author}<span class="author"><a href="{collection.fullUrl}?author={id}" rel="author">by {displayName}</a></span>{.end}
      {.section categories}<span class="categories">in {.repeated section @}<a href="{collection.fullUrl}?category={@|url-encode}" rel="tag">{@}</a>{.alternates with}, {.end}</span>{.end}
```

Then I simple wanted to move was in the post footer there to post header so I took the post footer code and moved it there.

```
<header>
            {.if title}<h1 class="entry-title" data-content-field="title" itemprop="headline">{.passthrough?}<a href="{sourceUrl}">{title} <span>&rarr;</span></a>{.or}<a href="{fullUrl}">{title}</a>{.end}</h1>{.end}
            <div class="article-meta">
                  <span class="date"><a href="{fullUrl}"><i class="icon-calendar"></i><time class="published" datetime="{addedOn|date %F}" itemprop="datePublished">{addedOn|date %B %d, %Y}</time></a></span>
                  {.section author}<span class="author"><span class="delimiter">/</span><a href="{collection.fullUrl}?author={id}" rel="author"><i class="icon-user"></i>{displayName}</a></span>{.end}
                  {.passthrough?}{.or}{.section sourceUrl}<span class="source"><span class="delimiter">/</span><a href="{sourceUrl}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-share"></i>Source</a></span>{.end}{.end}
                  {.section tags}<div class="tags"><i class="icon-tag"></i>{.repeated section @}<a href="{collection.fullUrl}?tag={@|url-encode}" rel="tag">{@}</a>{.alternates with}, {.end}</div>{.end}
                  {.section categories}<div class="categories"><i class="icon-bookmark"></i>{.repeated section @}<a href="{collection.fullUrl}?category={@|url-encode}" rel="tag">{@}</a>{.alternates with}, {.end}</div>{.end}

                  <div class="shareLoveButtons">
                    {@|like-button}
                    {@|social-button-inline}
                    {postItemInjectCode}
                  </div>
              </div>
```

I realize this could be to specific for a community question, so I'm not asking how to make this work per-se, just if it should work. If not, why? and where can I find documentation on that? I've looked at all of the developer docs and I'm not seeing where it talks about that. Is there something about annotations or code injection that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would first double check your FTP settings. In fact, FTP protocol is not supported, only SFTP and Git are. Make sure you follow these instructions: http://developers.squarespace.com/initial-setup.

I can tell you from using Squarespace Developer Mode 24/7 that I've not once experienced an issue where my updates don't get to the server, so my guess is that your SFTP app isn't configured properly.

Are you able to **download** the template files to your computer first? From your wording, it sounds like you are able to do.

What does the "Developer" page inside of the CMS show? It should show your SFTP/Git activity there.

Comment: The "Developer" page log shows that I've uploaded the blog.item file multiple times. Yes, I'm using SFTP as well. Again, my tweek.less uploads work fine. I change anything there or anything in the .region files and things work as expected.

Comment: Also, when I re-download the blog.item file from SFTP, it does show the changes I've made. Still, it is not effecting the live page.